# Jquery popUp menu with mouseenter then bind mouseleave fadeOut with delay

Tags: jquery, bind

I have some `DIV` that fades in by clicking another DIV trigger element. I cannot came up with a script that will:

- On mouse leave -**fade out** the `DIV` with some delay (ex 500ms), but if one mouseover again on it before those 500ms executes - to regain somehow the element visibility.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This oughta do it for you!

Here's a demo on JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bCCnB/

```
$('#divid').mouseout(function() {
    var timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    }.bind(this), 500);
    $(this).data('timeout', timeout);
});

$('#divid').mouseover(function() {
    var timeout = $(this).data('timeout');
    if (timeout) {
        window.clearInterval(timeout);
        $(this).data('timeout', null);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why no love?  Doesn't this do what you want?

Comment: No, lot of love, you my new jQuery hero. Since you've earned this title could you help me with similar problem. div is triggered and then after mouseover then mouseout and then click on body (everywhere) area besides the opened div, it's closing? If so you'll be my all time hero (even maybe your small statue on my desk)